# CONVERTIR PAGINA .NET A REACT

Tags: reactjs, .net

**HOLA TENGO QUE ARMAR UN PROYECTO BASTANTE LARGO EN DONDE UNA WEB E COMMERCE HECHA EN .NET CON C# QUIERE PASAR A UNA WEB COMPLETAMENTE NUEVA ARMADA CON REACT
ME PODRIAN ORIENTAR UN POCO EL PASO A PASO QUE DEBERIA IR VIENDO PRIMERO U ARMAR PRIMERO? GRACIAS!**

Comment: Primero: No debes escribir todo el texto en mayúsculas. Segundo: ¿Por qué desean hacer esto? Reactjs es para crear interfaces de usuarios notables, pero en el lado del servidor te conviene seguir con .NET y C#. ¿Qué motiva el cambio? Sí utilizaría ReacJs con .NET sin dudas. Pero no me queda claro lo de cambiar todo a React.

Comment: Eso mismo pregunte yo pero es algo que no habian definido aun, de todas maneras yo me empece a ocupar como si quedara front con React y back con .Net

Answer (score 0):

Este tipo de proyectos deben ser bien evaluados (en ocasiones, las empresas quieren actualizar sus sistemas para estar a la moda).

Para este caso en particular tendría en cuenta los siguientes puntos:

- **Backend**: Con una Web API (C#) con .NET Core 7.0 (ya que estamos). Esto con los proyectos asociados a la API y base de datos (con Entity Framework y todos los esquemas de seguridad aplicados).
- **Frontend**: Utilizaría Razor (cshtml) siempre con .NET Core 7.0 y React para darle la interfaz de usuario segura y potente.

Pero esa conversión directa, bajo mi punto de vista, no existe. Se debe realizar una importante tarea de actualización de código (en ambos frentes).